# Why isn't ContentChild reading the passed in element?

Tags: angular

I have an AuthComponent and a LoginSignupComponent. I want to pass in a form to the LoginSignupComponent and display fields specific to logging in or signing up.

Here is my LoginSignUp Component:

```
`export class LoginSignupView implements OnInit {
  @Input() public authForm: FormGroup;

  @Input() public mode: 'login' | 'signup' = 'login';

  @ContentChild(LoginDirective, { read: TemplateRef }) loginTemplate;
  @ContentChild(SignupDirective, { read: TemplateRef }) signupTemplate;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Inside of login, authForm: ",this.authForm)
    console.log("Inside of login, loginTemplate: ",this.loginTemplate)
  }

}`
```

and that component's template:

```
`<ng-container [ngSwitch]="mode">
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'login'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="loginTemplate">Test</ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'signup'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="signupTemplate"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
</ng-container>`
```

Then in my AuthComponent I want to maintain the form and pass it in. It will default to login. For now instead of a form I am using p tag for testing. This is my Auth template:

```
`<app-login [mode]="login" [authForm]="authForm">
    <p *login>
      Static Card Template
    </p>
</app-login>`
```

The login directive is nothing special. Its just a directive, and it has no logic in it.

```
`@Directive({
  selector: '[login]'
})
export class LoginDirective {

  constructor() { }

}`
```

This should work right? Or am I missing something and not understanding how ngTemplateOutlet works. I have been trying to follow this guide

https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/

Comment: Try accessing the `@ContentChild` variable in [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) rather than `ngOnInit`. The components are likely not rendered when `ngOnInit` fires.

Comment: You mean trying console.log it in the ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook?

Comment: Moving the console.log to that life cycle hook still logged loginTemplate variable as undefined.

Comment: Just for a test, try logging the values to the console after a delay: `ngOnInit() { setTimeout(() => { console.log(...); }, 2000); }`, and check in the console if `this.authForm` and `this.loginTemplate` are correct.

Comment: The correct hook is ngAfterContentInit. The name of it should make obvious why.

Comment: I have tried all of the above. For some reason it keeps coming up as undefined. I had pushed up my changes to me repo here https://github.com/omikolaj/movies-place. The file is in app>views>auth. I have no idea why its not working.